# Modifying current process' pte through /dev/mem?

Tags: linux-kernel

AFAIK, `/dev/mem` presents physical memory to user, and it's usually being used for device read/write through MMIO. In my use case, I want to modify current process' pte so that two ptes will point to the same physical page. In particular, I move a x86_64 binary above 4G virtual space and mmap virtual space below 4G. I want to make 4G above pte and 4G below pte point to the same physical page, so that when I write into 4G above vaddr and read from 4G below pte, I get the same result. Sample code might look like below:

```
*(unsigned char *)vaddr1 = 7 // write into 4G above vaddr1

val = *(unsigned char *)vaddr2; // read from 4G below vaddr2 

printf("val should be 7, %d\n", val);
```

But after I modify 4G below pte to point to physical page pointed by 4G above pte through `/dev/mem`, kernel give me message below,

```
BUG: Bad page map in process mmap  pte:8000000007eb2067 pmd:07acb067
page:ffffea00001fac80 count:0 mapcount:-1 mapping:          (null) index:0x101b7b
page flags: 0x4000000000000014(referenced|dirty)
addr:0000000101b7b000 vm_flags:00100073 anon_vma:ffff880007ab0708 mapping:          (null) index:101b7b
Pid: 609, comm: mmap Tainted: G    B        3.5.3 #7
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff8107abcc>] ? print_bad_pte+0x1d2/0x1ea
 [<ffffffff8107bf18>] ? unmap_single_vma+0x3a0/0x56d
 [<ffffffff8107c745>] ? unmap_vmas+0x2c/0x46
 [<ffffffff8108106b>] ? exit_mmap+0x6e/0xdd
 [<ffffffff8101cc4f>] ? do_page_fault+0x30f/0x348
 [<ffffffff81020ce6>] ? mmput+0x20/0xb4
 [<ffffffff810256ae>] ? exit_mm+0x105/0x110
 [<ffffffff8103bb6c>] ? hrtimer_try_to_cancel+0x67/0x70
 [<ffffffff81026b59>] ? do_exit+0x211/0x711
 [<ffffffff810272e0>] ? do_group_exit+0x76/0xa0
 [<ffffffff8102731c>] ? sys_exit_group+0x12/0x19
 [<ffffffff812f3662>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
 BUG: Bad rss-counter state mm:ffff880007a496c0 idx:0 val:-1
 BUG: Bad rss-counter state mm:ffff880007a496c0 idx:1 val:1
```

I guess kernel will examine if the pte has been modified, and I did something wrong. Here are vaddr1 and vaddr2's pte before/after my pte rewriting.

```
above 4G pte: 0x8000000007eb2067
below 4G pte: 0x0000000007ea7067
after rewriting pte...
above 4G pte: 0x8000000007eb2067
below 4G pte: 0x8000000007eb2067
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Note: Now I know I should release the physical page pointed by vaddr2's pte, otherwise kernel will note that physical page isn't pointed by any pte and give those error. But how? I try to use `__free_page`, but get error below.

```
BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffebe00008001c
IP: [<ffffffff8106b908>] __free_pages+0x4/0x2a
PGD 0
Oops: 0000 [#2] PREEMPT SMP
CPU 0
```

Comment: What I know is part of pte stores physical page address, and the rest of it stores permission bits and something else. Do I miss something?

Comment: O.K., now I found there are two problems at least. First, although both pte of vaddr1 and vaddr2 point to the same physical page, I need to add the correct offset to the physical address stored in pte to get the right value. Second, the original physical page (p1) pointed by vaddr2 is kind of becoming a orphan. When process terminated, and Linux reclaims its resource, Linux will notice there is something wrong to p1 and give those error message.